# Python - Data Frames, adding a column

Tags: python

I have a data frame that has some 100 rows. I would like to assign a unique number (not from index, but business logic based number) to each of those rows. There is a method which assigns unique keys (numbers). I am unable to assign values individually. Need some help

```
Data Frame data is as follows

customer_key
825486
457347
641996
1006860
1078894
```

The method that assigns unique ID is

```
def getuniqid(data):
    from time import time
    skey_list = []
    for row in data.count()-1:
            skey_list.append(int(time()*10000000))
            return skey_list
```

I want to be able to assign unique number for all individual rows (there is business logic behind generating unique number, for i am doing this simple int(time)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 2):

I think you need loop by range created by length of `df` and then get `return` outside of `for` loop:

```
def getuniqid(data):
    from time import time
    skey_list = []
    for row in range(len(data)):
            skey_list.append(int(time()*10000000))
    return skey_list

data['new'] = getuniqid(data)
```

Or is possible loop by some column of `DataFrame`:

```
def getuniqid(data):
    from time import time
    skey_list = []
    for row in data['customer_key']:
            skey_list.append(int(time()*10000000))
    return skey_list

data['new'] = getuniqid(data)
```

---

```
print (data)
   customer_key                new
0        825486  15073574836092810
1        457347  15073574836092810
2        641996  15073574836092810
3       1006860  15073574836092810
4       1078894  15073574836092810
```

Comment: Hey! I think you missed **I want to be able to assign unique number for all individual rows**. This is about creating unique ids for every row.

Comment: Yes, but OP write also `(there is business logic behind generating unique number, for i am doing this simple int(time)`.  So I understand question different.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

string = u"""customer_key
825486
457347
641996
1006860
1078894"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))

millisecondsnow = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
df["key"] = [millisecondsnow + i for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output:

```
    customer_key    key
0   825486  1507368278082
1   457347  1507368278083
2   641996  1507368278084
3   1006860 1507368278085
4   1078894 1507368278086
```

Or from a library with key-gen:

```
import uuid
import pandas as pd

string = u"""customer_key
825486
457347
641996
1006860
1078894"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))

df["key"] = [uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(len(df))]
```